# Hochschild cohomology of category of modules over an algebra

Tags: ra.rings-and-algebras, homotopy-theory, homological-algebra

Let $A$ be a complex associative and unital algebra.
Denote by $A\text{-mod}$ the category of finite-dimensional left modules over $A$. This is an Abelian category and we denote by $\text{Ch}_{\ge 0} (A\text{-mod})$ the category of non-negative chain complexes in $A\text{-mod}$.

I now want to relate the Hochschild cohomology of the dg-category $\text{Ch}_{\ge 0} (A\text{-mod})$ to the Hochschild cohomology of $A$. Does the following make sense:
As indicated here

mathoverflow.net/questions/189/definition-of-hochschild-cohomology-of-a-dg-or-a-infinity-category

the Hochschild cohomology can be described as the derived natural endotransformations of the identity of $\text{Ch}_{\ge 0} (A\text{-mod})$ (if my interpretation is correct). So the Hochschild cochains are
\begin{align} \mathbb{R}\text{Nat} (\text{id}_{\text{Ch}_{\ge 0} (A\text{-mod})}, \text{id}_{\text{Ch}_{\ge 0} (A\text{-mod})}   ). \end{align} Btw: What is a good reference which describes Hochschild cohomology or rather Hochschild cochains in precisely this way?

We can now express this by the derived end
\begin{align}
\int_{X \in \text{Ch}_{\ge 0} (A\text{-mod})} \mathbb{R}\text{Hom} (X,X).
\end{align} 
Is this correct so far? Does the end really go over $\text{Ch}_{\ge 0} (A\text{-mod})$ or just $A\text{-mod}$? If so, why?

Comment: Does this paper of Francis, https://arxiv.org/pdf/1104.0181.pdf, help? Specfically, Proposition 4.36

Comment: Sorry, I somehow missed this comment. Yes, Propoosition 4.36 and also Corollary 4.38 definitely help with parts of the question. Thank you very much!